# Причислять к лику святых / Причислять к святому лику. Одинаков ли смысл выражений?

Tags: семантика

Можно ли употребить (правилен ли) второй вариант в разговорной речи? Например: "К святому лику тебя точно не причислят".

Comment: *Однозначен ли...* — Вы действительно спросили то, что хотели? Может, Вы хотели спросить, одинаков ли смысл тех выражений?

Comment: Одинаковы ли по значению и смыслу эти выражения?

Comment: Тогда я исправлю вопрос. А то Вы спросили что-то совсем другое :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это разные по смыслу выражения.**

Можно сказать: **святой (светлый, божественный) лик Богоматери**, можно употребить это выражение с иронией по отношению к кому-либо, **но причислить к святому лику нельзя; причисляют только к лику святых.**

Ли́ки свя́тости (лики святых) — различные категории, на которые в Православии принято разделять святых при их канонизации и почитании в зависимости от трудов их святой земной жизни.[https://wiki.sc/wikipedia/Лик_святости](https://wiki.sc/wikipedia/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

1. ЛИК, -а; м. 1. Трад.-поэт. Лицо. Печальный л. // Изображение лица божества, святого на иконах. Л. Богоматери. Л. Николая Чудотворца. 2. Книжн. О внешнем виде, облике чего-л. Лунный л. Л. солнца.
2. ЛИК, -а; м. Высок. **Единое множество, группа, собрание, сонм** (о тех, кого почитают, боготворят). Относиться к лику святых. Причислить к лику выдающихся людей. Возвести в лик страдальцев и мучеников.

Comment: *Это разные по смыслу выражения.* Как так? Вы же сами говорите, что **причислить к святому лику нельзя,** значит, у этого выражения смысла просто нету! Разве нет?

Comment: Я имела в виду выражения  "святой лик" и "лик святых", это они разные по смыслу.

Comment: А-а, не сообразил, простите.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, вы не совсем понимаете значение слова "лик" в данном контексте.

> Причислять к лику святых / Причислять к святому лику. Одинаков ли
>   смысл выражений?

У второго варианта смысла немного. 
"Лик" - это, попросту говоря, категория святых (блаженный, мученик, праведник и т. д. - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) 
Точное значение выражения "причислить к лику святых" - назначить "категорию" канонизируемому святому.

А вот что такое святой лик - не совсем понятно. Больше ассоциируется с иконой. Каким образом можно причислить кого-то к иконе - не представляю.

> Можно ли употребить (правилен ли) второй вариант в разговорной речи? 
>    Например: "К святому лику тебя точно не причислят".

Как следует из предыдущего, вариант следует признать ошибочным, и таким образом вопрос о эквивалентности выражений снимается сам собой.

> Если бы так не говорили, я бы не задала этот вопрос.

Ну нельзя же на каждый чих здравствовать. Говорят люди, не понимающие смысл выражения. Не надо брать с них пример.

Comment: *Ну нельзя же на каждый чих здравствовать. Говорят люди, не понимающие смысл выражения. Не надо брать с них пример.* Это точно! При непонимании сути чего только не исказят.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, так не говорят. Вас просто не поймут.

Comment: Если бы так не говорили, я бы не задала этот вопрос.

Comment: Мало ли кто как говорит. Мы же неграмотные фразы не считаем. Говорят и "ложить", и "пока суть да дело", например.